# reference other html class through inline css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress page and it's really annoying because I cannot customize the css for the "form confirmation pharagraph". They allow me to add custom css to the whole page, but then this is what happens:

```
    style="margin:0% 0% 0% 0%; padding:0% 0% 0% 0%;  border-width: px px  px px; border-style: ; border-color: ; box-shadow: px  px  px  ;    
background: transparent; background:transparent;  display:block; text-align:;    
/* Custom CSS for widget here. */
        color: #343635!important;
        background-color: #c7edc9!important;"
```

After "custom css" is the new code, but then the whole page looks with a green background. I want only this id "#ulpb_Row56199-column2", but if I try to add in the custom css something like:

#ulpb_Row56199-column2{ background-color: #c7edc9!important;} then it adds to the "element.style {" a line that is: `"#ulpb_Row56199-column2{ background-color: #c7edc9!important;}"`
and it then gets crossed out because "it's not a valid attribute". Ofc it's not a valid attribute, I want it to be as a separate part of the css...

any suggestions? I guess it's something like.. reference another class with the inline css code inside the style.

Thanks,

Comment: css in the `style` html attribute can only apply to that element, so it only accepts properties, not new selectors. I'd recommend modifying this in the theme CSS, if the theme allows you to add custom styles.

Comment: As @Shamsup mentioned - you can't do that. Why not go to Appearance > Customizer > Additional CSS and plop `#ulpb_Row56199-column2{ background-color: #c7edc9!important;}` in there?